# How to render information from a ForeignKey field through DetailView class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I have two models (Taxonomia and Distribucion) which are the following:

```
# models.py file

class Taxonomia(models.Model): 
    id_cactacea = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subfamilia = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Distribucion(models.Model):
    id_distribucion = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    localidad = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    taxonomia = models.ForeignKey(Taxonomia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

As you can see in Distribucion there is a one to many relationship with the Taxomia table.

Implement the two models in the "admin.py" file so that you can edit the Distribucion table from Taxonomia

```
class DistribucionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Distribucion
    extra = 0

class TaxonomiaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = None # desactivando accion de 'eliminar'
    list_per_page = 20
    search_fields = ('genero',)
    radio_fields = {"estado_conservacion": admin.HORIZONTAL}
    inlines = [DistribucionInline]

admin.site.register(Taxonomia, TaxonomiaAdmin)
```

In turn, the file "view.py" renders the Taxonomia table as follows:

```
from repositorio.models import Taxonomia, Distribucion

class CactaceaDetail(DetailView):
    model = Taxonomia
    template_name = 'repositorio/cactacea_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['distribuciones'] = Distribucion.objects.all()
        return context
```

I tried to access to context ['distribuciones'] information from the template as follows without getting any results:

```
{% for obj in object.distribuciones %}
    {{ obj.localidad }}
{% endfor %}
```

OBS: For each Taxonomia element there will be four elements from the Distribucion table, so I need to use a FOR loop

**Is the way I add the information from the Taxonomia table in the "CactaceaDetail" view correct?**

**Is the way I read the information in the template correct?**

**How could I visualize all the information that "CactaceaDetail" sends to the template using the DJANGO shell so that I can debug better in the future?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the "object" from your for loop in the template:

```
{% for obj in distribuciones %}
    {{ obj.localidad }}
{% endfor %}
```

The reason is because you are passing `distribuciones` in the regular context, not as part of the class `object` so you can't reference it with `object.distribuciones`.